# function definition gets parser error (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, function

Beginner matlab user here.
I'm trying to write a function that multiplies a and b and returns the product if a and b is positive and -abs(a*b) if any of them is negative. This is what I've got.

```
function y = MulAnd(a,b)
%MULAND Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
if(a<0||b<0)
    y = -(abs(a*b));
else
    y = a*b;
end
end
```

Matlab doesn't like it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My MATLAB likes it. When your MATLAB doesn't like it, what does it say?

Comment: Also, how are you trying to call the function? Are you passing scalars to your function? Maybe you misunderstood the error.

Comment: At the moment, it's scalars. At a later stage I want to expand it to vectors and do the multiplication and sign testing piece-wise. Do I need to write a for-loop?

Comment: It gets red at the last "end" at it tells me "An M-Lint problem analyzing this file caused your previous MATLAB session to terminate unexpectedly".

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-74JVT3/

Comment: Oleg, as far as I can see, that page only describes how to remove the warning once it happened. I want to prevent it from occuring in the first place. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something here and programs just crash regurly in matlab and you have to hide it.

Comment: Never seen that problem myself. Matlab very rarely crashes. Not something you should be seeing regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is fine, and I think @OlegKomarov 's comment contains the answer.

When MATLAB crashes unexpectedly due to a problem with the MATLAB Code Analyzer, it adds the name of the file that caused the problem to the file `MLintFailureFiles`. This causes the red indicator to appear in the MATLAB file when you later open it.

Try this:

1. Type `cd(prefdir)`.
2. Open `MLintFailureFiles`, and remove the name of the file (`MulAnd.m`).
3. Save and close `MLintFailureFiles`.

Now try again with `MulAnd`.

Comment: But why does it crash? Did I do something wrong the first time I ran it? I just don't want to hide warnings but address the underlying problem if it is possible.

Comment: If MATLAB is repeatedly or reproducibly crashing, that would be something to look into. This would seem like a simple piece of code, so I would be surprised if that were the case, but if it does then let's work that out. But if it just happened once, there could be any number of reasons - perhaps the file got corrupted somehow, and the Code Analyzer got confused when parsing it. I would follow the above, if it doesn't happen again don't worry, but if it repeatedly does then work that out.

Comment: Thanks, it's a little bit strange that such a simple piece of code crashed right away. But it hasn't happened again, so I guess it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following which will work with scalars or vectors

```
function y = MulAnd(a,b)
%MULAND Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
y = a.*b;
negative = a<0 | b<0;
y(negative) = -abs(y(negative));
end
```

Comment: Although it works to call the function, it still gives the same warning. Something has to be wrong in my matlab setup or something if such a simple function causes it to crash.